# Symfony Doctrine Transaction loop issue

Tags: symfony, transactions, doctrine

I am trying to create users and block their exam number based on user details 
Below is my code,

I am using transaction to see if the exam halls are available and revert creating the user if they are not available,

But roll back is also reverting the log tables i maintain to store issues in allocation.

```
foreach($user_details as $ky=> $user) {

$this->em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();


try {


    $this->em->persist($user);
    $this->em->flush();


    // this function checks if user details contains some condition
    // for allocation of exam hall,
    // like  fees paid etc
    $examHallAvailable = $this->checkHallavailable($user);

    if($examHallAvailable) {

        // updated exam details for user 
        $user->addExamHall($examHallAvailable);
        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();
        $this->em->getConnection()->commit();   
    } else {

        // i want to rollback creation of this user
        // but continue other user creation
        $this->em->getConnection()->rollBack();
    }

    // this adds a log of user add fail in another table
    $this->updateLog($user);
}catch(Exception $ex) {
    $this->em->getConnection()->rollBack();
}
```

I get below error if i remove rollback if exam hall flag is not there

```
 The optimistic lock on an entity failed.
```

How do i continue the for loop ignoring the errors for a user and also prevent the log table update from getting rolled back if there is an error?

Comment: Shouldn't your first `commit()` be AFTER the `flush()` ? or even no commit after your `persist($user)` at all. If I remember, `commit` end the transaction so you can't revert it. See the docs below, if there is problem during the flush it rollback, so the commit doesn't end the transaction, that's the rollback that ends it. https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#approach-2-explicitly
Let me know if I'm not clear here.

Comment: @Etshy ,  it reverts all the changes since the transaction start, that is my issue, as the log update also gets reverted if the commit line is not reached.

Comment: I don't know if you can check that but what if you call `remove($user)` instead of a rollback? I still don't understand why tou commit right after biginning a transaction though, it looks wrong to me, but I don't use ORM thyat much to be sure.

Comment: @Etshy , i removed that (typo),  i can use remove, but it would add to the auto increment id unnecessaryly, and if there are other things related to user like address, those objects would have to be removed as well

Comment: Ok. Are you sure there is no Exception thown by your `updateLog` and that revert the whole thing ?
Apart that, I can't see any reason for your log to be rolled back.

Comment: @Etshy, the rollback is giving the Optimistic lock error and hence the update log is not executed, also Exception roll back would revert the log also

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't understand the Exceptionwas thrown by the rollback. I don't know Doctrine ORM that much and never faced the issue so I can't help you more than that. Only thing I can do is to advice you to follow this part of the docs :  https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#locking-support. Sorry for not being able to help more than that.